# VSCode cannot find the Julia executable that exists

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am trying to get Julia 1.5.4 to work with VSCode but it doesn't. I don't understand why it's the case. I renewed the installation for each but the problem persists. This is my `Preferences > Settings > Julia: Executable Path`:
[image]

This path does indeed exist. This is my settings.json:

```
{
    "[julia]": {

        "editor.quickSuggestions": true,
        "editor.wordSeparators": "`~#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
    },
    "julia.executablePath": "/home/onur/julia-1.5.4/bin/julia"
}
```

Again. The path does exist. But each time I try to run my example code, this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: @NathanBoyer Why? This is Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your (Preferences > Settings > Julia: Executable Path), you should specify the path only, not the key-value pair. It's trying to find the executable at path ""julia.executablePath": "/home/onur/julia-1.5.4/bin/julia"". You want only the path. Ex. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNMSf.png) is what it shows in my setup.